# Embedding extra styles with noscript

Tags: css, xhtml

I have an XHTML strict page that has an invisible div that is controlled by Javascript. The div is set to transparent and visible by the script and a mouseover event to make the div opaque on hover.

When someone using a browser (or firefox with noscript) without javascript the div simply remains invisible. The problem with this is that I do not want the content to be inaccessible. I also do not want to leave the div visible then use the script to make it transparent as the div is located at the bottom of the document and it causes a noticeable flicker whenever a page loads.

I have tried using noscript tags to embed an additional style sheet that is only loaded for people without the luxury of Javascript but this fails the XHTML strict validation. Is there any other way to include extra styling information inside a noscript block that is XHTML valid?

**Ed:**

With a simple test case I get a validation error of: **document type does not allow element "style" here.**
This is with an empty XHTML Strict document with a style element inside a noscript element. The noscript is inside the body.

Comment: Anyone facing the same problem should probably have a look at [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9503382/2657549).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To clear up the validation issue: `noscript` is only allowed in the `body` element, `style` only allowed in the `head`. Therefore, the latter is not allowed within the former.

On the general issue: you'll want to make the `div` element visible by default, then hide it via CSS + javascript. This is the 'progressive enhancement' model. I notice you say you "don't want to do this because of the flicker", but I'm not sure exactly what's causing this - chances are you can fix it, so maybe you should post *that* as a question.

Comment: Yes, HTML5 [explicitly allows](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element) `noscript` in `head`.

Comment: A warning for people using WebForms, even though noscript can be used with style in head now. Any postback from updatepanel (if the response contains this tag) will apply said styles regardless if JS is allowed or not. A workaround is not rendering it in the head of the postback.

Answer (score 78):

noscript in head is valid HTML5. It wasn't valid before. I just tested it, it works in current Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera and IE.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <noscript>
            <style>body{background:red}</style>
        </noscript>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>is this red? it should <script>document.writeln("not");</script> be. <noscript>indeed.</noscript></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By far the best solution.

Answer (score 12):

## Note about my answer

I wrote this post after realizing it was dating from 2008

Since I had a similar problem, I thought continuing answering with a current answer.

## My actual answer

Like Boby Jack said, `style` tag is not allowed in body.  I myself did the exact thing as you (Joshua) about it. But Jack's "progressive enhancement" made me without non-abstract solution but then I realized a solution that I did not find answers on this thread.

It all depends of your styling structure.

My suggestion is to plainly use something like `modernizr` in the very begining of the head and use Paul Irish's HTML5Boilerplate recommendations.

## Long story short

1. Html tag has a `class` attributes with `no-js`
2. Head tag includes a first modernizr javascript as the first
3. CSS has the element (`.hide-me`) with `display:none` on its proper place
4. Then `.no-js .hide-me { display:block }`

## In detail

See Paul Irish's HTML5boilerplate, and adapt it to XHTML if you want :)

### 1. Html has a class attributes with `.no-js`

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

quoting from `html5boilerplate.com`

### 2. Head tag includes a first modernizr javascript as the first

Modernizr execution will build `html` attributes with what's supported.

Will build something similar to this:

```
<html class=" js flexbox canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths" lang="en">
```

**Note** this is from Google Chrome `modernizr` tests.

The first is `js` but if Modernizr did not run (no javascript) the `no-js` would stay there.

### 3. CSS has the element (`.hide-me`) with `display:none` on its proper place

... you know the rest :)

Comment: Doesn't work with XHTML 1.0 (neither Transitional, nor Strict). Reason: "class" is not allowed attribute in <html> tag.
I mean it will be shown OK in browser, BUT you will not pass XHTML validation (e.g. validator.w3.org).

Comment: Indeed, it is not XHTML 1.0 valid. But if you do not send header before content without specifying `application/xhtml+xml` [see W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#ref-rfc3236), it _also_ makes it invalid. Doesn't it :) But. I still think that disgressing that rule for the `<html/>` tag is a cheap price than ways of the past.

Answer (score 11):

Use a `script` block in the `head` to add a `style` element with `document.write`:

```
<head>
...
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
  document.write('<style type="text/css">.noscript{display:none}</style>');
 //]]>
 </script>
...
</head>
```

Comment: Careful with document.write() - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: I know this is from 2008, but dude the WHOLE POINT was to do this without javascript lmao

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** for **2016**:

From [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp):

> **Differences Between HTML 4.01 and HTML5**
>
> In HTML 4.01, `<noscript>` tag can only be used inside the `<body>`
> element.
>
> In HTML5, the `<noscript>` tag can be used both inside `<head>` and
> `<body>`.
>
> **Differences Between HTML and XHTML**
>
> In XHTML, the `<noscript>` tag is not supported.

**My solution for having expanded menus (lists, etc..)**

I've put in the header like this

```
<header>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/x_no_script.css">
    </noscript>
</header>
```

In the `x_no_script.css` I set the selectors that I wanted to

```
max-height: 9999px;
overflow: visible;
```

In this way, I have expanded menus when **JavaScript** is **disabled** or not exists.

Answer (score 0):

What validation error do you get?  `<noscript>` should be allowed in XHTML but it's block level, so make sure it's not in a `<p>`, `<span>`, etc

Comment: XHTML 1.0: `<noscript>` is only allowed in the body, `<script>` only in the head.

Answer (score 0):

In case XHTML is used, the trick is to use two CSS files. One global one and one js-one tweaking the global one for JavaScript-enabled browsers.

style.css:

```
.hidden {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

style-js.css:

```
.hidden {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
  <title>Test page</title>
  <link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    //document.write("<link href='css/style-js.css' rel='styleSheet' type='text/css' />"); 
    //is not legal in XHTML, we do the long way:
    var l=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","link");
    l.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    l.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    l.setAttribute("href", "/css/style-js.css");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(l);
  //]]>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="hidden">
    <p>Only displayed at JavaScript enabled browsers</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Main idea by [tutorials.de](http://www.tutorials.de/html-xhtml/252863-style-im-noscript-tag-nicht-valide.html). XHTML validity tip by [Estelle Weyl's Blog](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/05/including-javascript-in-xhtml/). createElementNS tip by [CodingForums](http://www.codingforums.com/showpost.php?s=41fd8825d2f084665736b5c71967ca5f&p=67618&postcount=7).

Comment: document.write is not valid XHTML

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I improved the code. Hopefully, it is valid now. Unfortunately, HTML Validator (http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/) does not check JavaScript code.