# Best way to manipulate many sliding objects with moo tools's Fx.Slide

Tags: javascript, loops, mootools, slide

I'm trying to think of the most elegant solution to handle multiple Fx.Slides within mootools. I'm developing a dictionary page with a very long list of words where there's a pair word -- translation and all the translations must be hidden by default showing just a word list. I'm looking for a solution that won't require creating a separate slide for each word on the page, so that they're created on-the-fly when a visitor clicks on a word because the size of the script and performance hit concern me. There's another problem in that their initial states must be set to 'hidden' beforehand and I don't want to do it in CSS (that would hide everything from people whose browsers don't support javascript).
Is anything of this sort possible or will I have to rely on creating slides in a loop (my element ids go like w01, w02, ...)? If so, how would I put that block inside a loop?

Comment: I added an alternative solution to add the event listeners just in case you have huge amounts of things you want to toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this question regarding if the user does not have Javascript [Embedding extra styles with noscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218162/embedding-extra-styles-with-noscript).

After that is taken care of we can concentrate in mootools. You want the elements to have `visability: hidden` when you load the page with Javascript. Give your elements a class so we can select them all at once. Example to initialize the elements.

```
$$('.sliders').each(function(el) {
    el.slide('hide').setStyle('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Now we need to handle the click event. The same goes here.

Example html:

```
<h3 class="slideIn" >Some title</h3>
<div class="sliders>Some lengthy text<div>
```

Example html:

```
$$('.slideIn').addEvent('click', function() {
    this.getNext().getChildren('.sliders').slide();
});
```

​
Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b4Zjs/

Edit: If there are a lot of elements that should have click events it's better to use event delegation. Then you are only adding one event listener to the page, and it can make a huge difference some times.

```
$('parent').addEvent('click:relay(h3.slideIn)', function(event, target) {
   target.getNext().getChildren('.sliders').slide();
});
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/b4Zjs/2/

Comment: Thank you so much. Knowing nothing about Javascript (or how to work on classes) I started doing loops with arrays and managed to hide elements sequentially using wordslide[i] = new Fx.Slide(myobject[i]).hide(); but that is wrong wrong wrong. Your solution is perfect, exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: 3axap Joe, there is nothing inherently wrong with your method. You had simply instantiated each word's `Fx.Slide` object and stored it in an array, to be iterated over when required. This is essentially the same thing as using `$$()`, except `$$()` creates the element list on-the-fly and then exposes `Array`-type methods.

Comment: Nils' method is superior only in that if your list is dynamically generated, calling `$$(.sliders)` will always return the complete list of words (with the `slider` class, anyways), as opposed to you having to maintain said list of words.