# <noscript> not working for firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this little bit of code for a fade in effect but for some reason firefox is not picking up the  which I need because the fade it doesn't work for firefox. What am I missing to get this to work?

```
<noscript>
</style>
<style type="text/css"> 
  body {display:inherit !important;} /*if they haven't got javascript we need to show the body       
</style>
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() { $("body").fadeIn(1500);});
</script>
```

the css

```
body {
     background-color:#000;
     overflow-x:hidden;
     -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
     display:none;}
```

Comment: You have a closing `</style>` in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a `<noscript>` tag anywhere but the `<body>` section of your document, and you can't have a `<style>` tag anywhere but the `<head>` section of your document (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218162/embedding-extra-styles-with-noscript) post).

An alternative way to do this would be to make the body tag default to `display: visible` and set the `display` property using JavaScript like so:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.body.style.display = "none";</script>
    ...
</body>
```

Then get rid of your `<noscript>` tag completely and remove the `display:none;` line from your CSS declaration.

The advantage of this is that if the browser doesn't have JavaScript enabled, your `<body>` tag will be visible, regardless of how the browser handles the `<noscript>` tag.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help! If you wouldn't mind accepting the answer, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Actually the `<noscript>` tag inside `<head>` is valid in HTML5, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1332058/994820