# jQuery sliders hidden at first: fallback for people without JavaScript

Tags: jquery, css, noscript

I have a small FAQ where people can click on a question link and the answer appears nicely, using jQuery `slideToggle()`.

The answers are hidden by default, you have to click on them to make them appear. **I do not want to have an initial slide in when the page is loaded.**

The problem is that people without JavaScript cannot make the answers appear. To allow these people to see them, they should be directly visible.

It is possible if I slide in the answers when the page is loaded, but I find the solution inelegant. Any idea how I could keep my solution ?

I made a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s5HNd/3/

My code:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<ul class="faqquestions">
    <li>
        <span class="faqlink">First Question</span>
        <div class="faqreponse">First answer</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="faqlink">Second question</span>
        <div class="faqreponse">Second answer</div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul.faqquestions li { cursor: pointer; }
div.faqreponse { overflow: hidden; }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $("ul.faqquestions li").each(function () {
        var tis = $(this), state = false, answer = 
            tis.children(".faqreponse").hide().css('height', 'auto').slideUp();

        $(this).children(".faqlink").click(function () {
            state = !state;
            answer.slideToggle(state);
        });
     });
});
```

Comment: There's always the `noscript` tag ?

Comment: @adeneo You are right, but I do not know how to use it without having to type the answers twice: once inside the hidden div, once inside the `noscript` tag.

Comment: at this point, I don't even bother worrying about people without javascript.  It's such an integral part of today's web experience.  I know that "Progressive Enhancement" is still taught in school, but by and large I've found the actual development community barely worries about things like js being disabled.  Other than that, there's nothing wrong with the method you've taken.

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch As a user of the NoScript extension on Firefox, I like to have a website available even for those without JS :) But my method only works when JS is enabled, that is why I am searching a solution.

Comment: Studies suggest that only an average of 1.3% of users these days are like you.  Chances are, you'll spend much more time, effort, (and as a result Opportunity Cost in $$) optimizing for those 1%, than you would optimizing for the remaining 99%.

Comment: aside from that, this is very basic in theory.  Display your questions as a list, and the answers as a child ul and li.  Use jquery to hide them on page ready.  And users with js enabled will have your functionality, while those without will just have a nicely styled FAQ page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218162/embedding-extra-styles-with-noscript) I discovered that the `noscript` tag can be but in the `head` and this is valid in HTML5. Moreover, styles can be written inside!

So the solution was to add this code between the `head` tags of the page:

```
<noscript>
<style>
    div.faqreponse {
        height: auto;
        overflow: visible;
    }
</style>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have the answers visible by default, and on page load (or even when each answer element is loaded) you can hide the answers via JavaScript (you might have to use `.slideToggle(0)` which should slide them closed immediately). That way those with JavaScript can still slide the answers open/closed, but they will show for non-JS users due to not being closed in the first place.

Admittedly, since you have to wait until things are loaded this may not be visually pleasing for JavaScript users (which is the majority of Internet users out there). I would weigh this carefully with the `noscript` suggestion. Do you expect a significant portion of your audience to have JS disabled?

Comment: I do not think many people visit my website without JS, but the FAQ was the only problematic page. Do you have an idea how to use `noscript` without typing the answers twice ?

Comment: I think `noscript` tags stick around in your markup without being visible if the browser loads with JavaScript enabled. Maybe you could write a short function that copies the text out of them and puts it into your sliding answer elements for JavaScript users? That way your answers will only be typed by you once in the `noscript` tags, but will appear for JS users. Granted, they will be duplicated in the rendered markup, but people don't usually care as much about the rendered markup as long as it looks nice (and isn't something like a table layout :P).

Comment: Actually you can write styles inside a `noscript` tag and it can be put inside `head`, so it solved the problem (see my answer) :)

Comment: Wow, I thought I had seen someone say it wasn't valid HTML5, that is super cool.