# Scrollbar Visible on Preloading

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am using a preloader before the website loads. also, I want to make sure that there is no scrolling happening or any scrollbar present while the contents are loaded. I'm using the below code.

```
<div id="preloader"></div>

#preloader
{
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    -webkit-scrollbar: none;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(../images/preloader.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

But still there is scrollbar visible and the page is scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a class to the `<body>` during loading and remove once completed.

```
body.loading {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: good answer, but if I hardcode it into the page there will be no scrolling if javascript is disabled ... or am I missing something ?

Comment: @webman - you are right! In fact, there are many things to consider here including accessibility. Here are some useful links that I would consider in combination with this solution, including doing it a completely different way: 
> https://dockyard.com/blog/2020/03/02/accessible-loading-indicatorswith-no-extra-elements
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218162/embedding-extra-styles-with-noscript

Answer (score 1):

```
enter code he
```

```css
body.loading{overflow:hidden}

#preloader
{
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    -webkit-scrollbar: none;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(../images/preloader.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader"></div>
```

re