# How can i use [display = "none"] when javascript is disabled on client browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i use this

```
document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
```

when javascript is disabled on client browser? I added this [w3school loading animation tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader5) unto my site but it keep rotating when javascript is disabled on client browser and blocking the

```
<noscript>Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

Should i just create an image and just use `z-index: 9999;` to declare `Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript!` or are they any alternative?

I created a demo page of it what it look like when you have javascript disabled and how it infinitely just rotating and blocking `<noscript>`.     [demo page here](http://glxqnkricwnbjmke.000webhostapp.com/A/exception.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedding extra styles with noscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218162/embedding-extra-styles-with-noscript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it to `display: none;` by default, and show it through javascript, so if javascript is disabled, it would not show

Comment: Thanks this perfectly work also i set the whole HTML content too with `display: none; ` cuz whole content is run by `setTimeout` to show up so no javascript they won't see a thing except the `<noscript>` . I would also study other answer they look nice

Answer (score 3):

Just add CSS into `noscript` tag:

```
<noscript>
  <style type="text/css">
    selector {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</noscript>
```

If you do the opposite by accessing styling through JS, you will encounter flickering / showing unnecessary elements before script is loaded and executed.